# Finding Near duplicate records in a table with 100M records in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, duplicates, arabic

I have a customer table with more than 100 million recrods. the customer_id is unique. but some customers have more than 1 customer_id. so in some fileds id's are diffrent and the rest of the fields values are duplicate or near duplicate. I specially focused on First names and Family names to detect near duplicate records.( Names are in Arabic format and not romanized). Help with this issue please.

Comment: it is virtually impossible to answer this unless you provide more information: schema, example values, expected output, etc

Answer (score 1):

"the rest of the fields values are duplicate or near duplicate..."

I would use two approaches: one for duplicate fields and a different one for near duplicates.

1. Duplicate fields can be solved by something similar to @Emanuels answer.
2. Near duplicates are more difficult and need a lot of trial and error. Most similarity measures I know of are build around English, I don't know how well they perform with Arabic names. Please have a look at `utl_match`:

   SELECT utl_match.edit_distance('mErry','mArry') FROM DUAL;

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from CUSTOMER
 where CUSTOMER_ID <> (select min(CUSTOMER_ID)
                         from CUSTOMER C
                        where C.FIRST_NAME = FIRST_NAME
                          and C.LAST_NAME = LAST_NAME)
```

Comment: names are not exactly the same. they are near duplicate records

Comment: e.g. record 1 : name = 'mErry', record 2 : name = 'mArry'